# Localization not working in production (it works locally): I always get the key instead of the translation

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-9

I use the file `en.json` for the translations. I have a key inside it that works locally. I do not know why it does not work when I deploy the project on the server.
In production environment I just get the key not translated.

This is what I tried:

- `echo App::getLocale()` (it returns correctly "en")
- `php artisan config:cache`
- `php artisan config:clear`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan optimize:clear`
- `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

A common issue when this happen is uppercase in lang directories.

If you are using a windows local environment will work, but if you are deploying to a linux server (case sensitive) the same solution won't work.

Comment: That was exactly my problem, thanks! I changed the pt-br lang directory to pt-BR and now it's working on linux prod server.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

it will be clear all cache (view, cache, config, route)

[https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys:~:text=by%20your%20application.-,For%20this%20reason%2C%20Laravel%20also%20provides%20support%20for%20defining%20translation%20strings,.,-Retrieving%20Translation%20Strings](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys:%7E:text=by%20your%20application.-,For%20this%20reason%2C%20Laravel%20also%20provides%20support%20for%20defining%20translation%20strings,.,-Retrieving%20Translation%20Strings)

Comment: tried, (i edited first post)

Comment: do You change APP_LOCALE  in your .env file on local machine ,but did'n change in production? also can you share more information

Comment: I did not change APP_LOCALE in env file. I am not able to share more information, its just it. Its not the first laravel project I do (I did 20 or something), it's the first time this happens

Comment: please check the highlighed doc..